Image Component Stretches in @nextui-org/react, Ignoring Parent Element Constraints
I've encountered an issue with the Image component from @nextui-org/react where the image stretches beyond the parent element, ignoring its constraints. This behavior is different when compared to using a native <img> element, which renders the image properly within its container.
Steps to reproduce:

Using a native <img> tag (works as expected):
"use client";

import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody } from "@nextui-org/card";

const Test1 = () => {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardBody>
                <img
                    width={2000}
                    height={2000}
                    alt="test1"
                    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/product-page-03-product-01.jpg"
                />
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default Test1;

The image fits perfectly inside the Card component.

Using the NextUI Image component (causes the issue):
"use client";

import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody } from "@nextui-org/card";
import { Image } from "@nextui-org/react";

const Test2 = () => {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardBody>
                <Image
                    width={2000}
                    height={2000}
                    alt="test2"
                    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/product-page-03-product-01.jpg"
                />
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default Test2;

In this case, the image stretches and does not fit within the parent Card component, no matter how I adjust the width/height properties or apply classes such as w-full or h-auto.


The Image component should behave like the native <img> element, fitting appropriately inside the parent container without stretching.
Edit: Removing height makes the built-in Skeleton not show up at all.
Video demonstrating the current & expected output:
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/b2905fa6-1b0f-4f3a-a800-ad0fa72a9f40
Video demonstrating that removing the height will work fine but the Skeleton doesn't show up:
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/cf18d3c8-550e-4682-8537-1622d3c5e8fa
See the issue

Please add code in which are you applying classes such as w-full or h-auto. You may also add a image in the above question to show current output & expected output using image.

Please see the edit section. I added videos demonstrating the situation.

You can add styles to Card and Image to add a minimal height. Maybe it helps you with your issue. You can test with code below or see it on CodeSandbox.
<Card className="w-full">
  <CardBody>
    <Image
      className="min-h-[300px]"
      alt="test1"
      src="https://play.tailwindcss.com/img/beams.jpg"
    />
  </CardBody>
</Card>

